# Translation of "Why for you". (Softer, politer synonyms for "It's not your business")

Tags: phrase-request, politeness

The title really sounds silly but it is *true* translation from local language to English. I believe (and sure) it's not correct.

Can someone suggest to me the correct word (phrase)?

The intention is: "Its not your business".

The context: dialogue between two school children. The point is, one meddles in other's business.

Comment: *none of your business* is common to use. The phrase is perfect. Why you need an alternative to that?

Comment: yes it is @MaulikV But I personally feel its disrespectful (very informal) IMHO?

Comment: @CopperKettle the context is between two school  children. The point is one involving in other matter.

Comment: Since when do school children care about being formal or respectful?... I wish American kids were... but they're not... they say "it's none of your bee's wax"... or "butt out"... or "this is an A and B conversation... C... you're way out"... Ah... childhood. This comment brought to you by an 80s child.

Comment: May I know the reason for Down vote?

Comment: @Ravan: Someone's just being spiteful. Happens all the time here.

Comment: @NES: You shouldn't have removed "Why for you": It's an important clue. Put it back.

Comment: @Ricky I didn't. I only added a *to* after *suggest*.

Comment: @NES: I just looked into it. Ravan herself took it out. I don't know why. It's a mystery. Please accept my sincere apologies.

Comment: @Ricky I will add it back, I felt that is the reason for downvote. thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a polite version. Okay, there could be *several ways* to tell that. Here are a few alternatives to 'none of your business' that come to my mind.

> I think I can tackle it in my own ways 
>  I don't think I need help, I can handle it well 
>  Thanks for the suggestion, but no thanks

To me, these are less *severe* than telling 'none of your business' straightforwardly.

Answer (score 3):

**What's it to you?**

**Why, what's it to you?**

**How is this any of your business?**

**Why are you so concerned?**

**Don't worry about it.** (This is actually very obnoxious if you think about, but many people fail to notice the connotation).

**You don't need this.**

Take your pick.

Comment: +1 for "Don't worry about it".  Any of the others still sound rude to me.

Comment: The first few are harsher than "none of your business" imo

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with you that "It's none of your business" is rather terse and can be seen to be impolite, I don't think there is a single phrase that literally means the same but is seen more formal and polite. A short explanation why a question is off limits, however, allows the conversation (or the person asking) to move on. You can give a vague, one or two word answer to the question to close the issue, but you probably won't have to.

Answer (score 1):

The situation you are dealing with will have a lot to do with what polite terms will work.  My favorite is "I appreciate your offer to help, but I need to work on this on my own for now."

Answer (score 1):

- This is none of your concern.
- This is not relevant to you.
- This probably isn't relevant to you. (softer)